# Method Overriding of diffrent Return type to void

Tags: java, methods, overriding

let's say we have this method

```
 public class Animal {
     public void eat() { }
}
```

and on another class that extends Animal has this method

```
public String eat(){}
```

is this considered as method overriding? because I've heard that you can use different return types in method overriding providing they have the same method arguments

Comment: it is not even possible.

Answer (score 6):

This is neither overloading , nor overriding ! It is compilation error .

In Java it is possible to define two or more methods within the same class that share the same name, as long as their parameter declarations are different. When this is the case, the methods are said to be overloaded, and the process is referred to as **method overloading.**

Following are rules of **method overriding** in java which must be followed while overriding any method. **private, static and final method can not be overridden.**

1)Method signature must be same including return type, number of method parameters, type of parameters and order of parameters.

2)Overriding method can not throw higher Exception than original or overridden method.  This rule only applies to checked Exception in Java, overridden method is free to throw any unchecked Exception.

3)Overriding method can not reduce accessibility of overridden method , means if original or overridden method is public than overriding method can not make it protected.

Comment: Please note that we can change the return type to a subclass of the original return type as @Timmy mentioned.

Answer (score 5):

You can only change the return type to a subclass of the original return type.

Comment: strange, but `String` is subclass of `Object` why is not this correct?

Comment: OP has not used Object as the return type in parent method, but he has rather used `void`

Answer (score 3):

All answers are correct from a technical point of view because Void is a class in Java that no other class can extend and when methods are overridden the return-type has to be a sub-type of the original type (parentReturnType.isAsignableFrom(overriddenReturnType)).

But from a practical point of view the question is still valid and it would have made sense to make an excuse for the special case void. The only value a variable of the type Void can hold is null. Further no variable can have the primitive type void. Finally you can not compile this code:
Void result = object.notify();
So in the end it would have made sense to specify Java differently when 1.5 was introduced and allow overriding void return types with any other type.

Therefore the only reasonable answer is IMHO it is not possible because Java was designed such that this is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

This not correct Code, as two methods with same name should return same value, only arguments can be differents
Overriding is having same method with same arguments in the subclass
Overloading having same method name with different argumens

Answer (score 0):

The return type of a method is not part of that method's signature.

When you call `eat()` on the subclass, java looks at the signature you provided (`eat` with no parameters) and starts looking for a method with this signature, starting in the class of the instance type of the object you call it on (and searches through its ancestors if it fails to find it).

So, methods called on a subclass will always run the overridden methods (they're found first).

A critical 'point' of OO (specifically polymorphism) is that a subclass can be passed in where the superclass was expected.
If a method wants to call the superclass' `eat()` method and get a void, but you passed a subclass into that method of which `eat()` returned a String; you can see that method will call the subclass' eat and get an unexpected value.
You can see why this could be a problem. :I

So, overriding methods must return the same type or a subclass of the type returned by the parent.
(Similar principles apply as to why you can return a subclass; I'll let you think about it c: )

Answer (score 0):

It's neither overriding nor overloading, it creates compilation error.

Two methods with same name, different param numbers or different type of params known as overload method, return type may be same or different. It may be in same class or parent, child classes.

Two methods having same param numbers, same types, same return types but one is in parent class and other is in child class are known as overrided methods.